# Show the name of the chosen variation under the product title on the My Account > Downloads page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

By default WooCommerce shows the attribute of a variable product in the title and I'm using this code to show the attribute below the title in the cart and checkout pages:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
```

But that doesn't work in My Account page, users see the full product name with no attribute.

To fix it I'm using the code below to show the attribute in the product title:

```
function show_attributes_outside_title_1( $enabled ) {
    if ( !is_account_page() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'show_attributes_outside_title_1' );

function show_attributes_outside_title_2( $enabled ) {
    if ( !is_account_page() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', 'show_attributes_outside_title_2' );
```

But I'd like to show the attribute below the title (or a new column), it's easier to read and goes with the same desing you see in the cart and checkout pages.

Comment: You can override the WooCommerce `order-details-item.php` template located in `/plugins/woocommerce/order/order-details-item.php`. https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-order-order-details-item.html

Comment: I just checked that file but the correct one is `order-downloads.php`. But I'd like to change this via a funcion to avoid messing with templates if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion in the initial part of the question.

You say you want to show the attribute under the product title on the cart and checkout page but then return `__return_false`, do you intend to do the opposite?

**SOLUTION #1**

**You may want to reverse the check** to make sure that your chosen product variation attribute is shown under the product name **on your account page under Downloads** *(as evidenced by your comment above)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', 'show_attributes_outside_title_1' );
function show_attributes_outside_title_1( $enabled ) {
    if ( is_account_page() ) {
        $enabled = true;
    }
    return $enabled;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', 'show_attributes_outside_title_2' );
function show_attributes_outside_title_2( $enabled ) {
    if ( ! is_account_page() ) {
        $enabled = false;
    }
    return $enabled;
}
```

**SOLUTION #2**

If you want to leave the code in your question unchanged you can use the `woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product` hook where `download-product` **is the id of the product name column** *(in the /my-account/downloads/ page)*. [Here](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-templates-order-order-downloads.html#source-view.42) the documentation.

Finally, with the `wc_get_formatted_variation` function **you can get the name of the chosen variation**. For more information on parameters [read](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-product-functions.html#source-view.360) the documentation.

```
// shows the variation chosen in the product name in the download table of the my-account page
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'change_product_download_name', 10, 1 );
function change_product_download_name( $download ) {
    // gets the product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] );
    // gets the name of the produc
    $product_name = $download['product_name'];
    // if the product is a variation
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        // gets the name of the product with the chosen variation
        $product_name = $product->get_name() . " - " . wc_get_formatted_variation( $product, true, false, false );
    }
    // print the product name (with or without product url)
    if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $product_name ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo esc_html( $product_name );
    }
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: I tested your code and I was getting [duplicate attributes](https://i.ibb.co/JxrnkB8/duplicated.png), so I modified it a bit and got it the [same way it looks on my cart](https://i.ibb.co/fr2PxT6/attributes.png). I'll add the code as a new answer in case anybody else needs it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I changed Vincenzo's answer a bit to make it look the same way I see the attributes in my Cart and Checkout pages. Here's the code in case anybody else needs it:

```
// Shows the variation chosen in the product name in the download table of the my-account page
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_downloads_column_download-product', 'change_product_download_name', 10, 1 );
function change_product_download_name( $download ) {
    // gets the product object
    $product = wc_get_product( $download['product_id'] );
    // gets the name of the product
    $product_name = $download['product_name'];
    // define variable
    $product_attributes = '';
    // if the product is a variation
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
        // gets the name of the product with the chosen variation
        $product_name = $product->get_name();
        $product_attributes = wc_get_formatted_variation( $product, true, true, false );
    }
    // print the product name (with or without product url)
    if ( $download['product_url'] ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $download['product_url'] ) . '">' . esc_html( $product_name ) . '</a><p>' . esc_html( $product_attributes ) . '</p>';
    } else {
        echo esc_html( $product_name ) . '<p>' . esc_html( $product_attributes ) . '</p>';
    }
}

// Shows variation outside title in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_variation_title_include_attributes', '__return_false' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_attribute_in_product_name', '__return_false' );
```

The last two filters replace my code and the first part solves the issue in the Downloads page.

Comment: Before checking the product type `if ( $product->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {` you should initialize the variable `$product_attributes` otherwise you will receive a notice `Notice: Undefined variable: product_attributes` because the variable is only valued if the product is a variation.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I just updated the code with your suggestion.